# Function that calculates number of days between 2 dates, accepts the start date and end date, then returns how many days it covers over that period

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, sql-function

I have to do something similar to this, and I need to spool file as well to css

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NumberOfDays
(in_date IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
days NUMBER;
BEGIN
days:= TRUNC(SYSDATE - in_date);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I need to create function NumberOfDays that calculates the number of days between 2 dates, accepts the start date and end date then returns how many days it covers over that period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code is almost there. You just need to add a second `in` parameter. Also, you need to `return` the result, so it gets back to the caller. Finally, there is no need for an intermediate variable. You can compute and return immediatly.

```
create or replace function number_of_days(start_date in date, end_date in date)
return number
is
begin
    return trunc(end_date - start_date);
exception
    when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
select number_of_days(date '2020-06-01', date '2020-06-06') res from dual
```

Yields:

```
| RES |
| --: |
|   5 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time!